# GA Ecommerce - no data

Tags: google-analytics

I am not able to track ecommerce data in google analytics. I have tried to change it in many ways, but I can't see any data in Conversions > Ecommerce. There are 0 ecommerce hits.

```
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
ga('create', 'UA-123456-1', 'auto');
ga('require', 'ec');
ga('ec:addProduct', {"id":"123456","name":"Product name","brand":"321654","price":"0","category":"category\/subcategory"}); 
ga('ec:setAction', 'detail');
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

I am trying to make it work for three days. In firebug I can see data being sent. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You are only sending in a product detail view, and not an actual transaction. If you want to measure a transaction, then refer to this guide: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/enhanced-ecommerce#measuring-transactions. You need to set the product action to "purchase" with the appropriate parameters.

If you are only sending in a "detail" action (without impressions), then you should still be able to see (without much detail) those hits in the `Ecommerce > Overview > View Full Reports`, or in the `Shopping Analysis > Shopping Behaviour` report, under "Sessions with Product View". Unfortunately, as I mentioned.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but there is no transaction, I want only to measure showing product detail page. Even in this case I need to use transaction?

Comment: OK, in your question you said "There are 0 transactions", so I assumed that you wanted an actual "transaction".

Comment: I'm sorry, I am new in ecommerce analytics